# What should we use, @Input & @Output decorators or Services in Angular? What would be the correct use case for each of the features?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, decorator

What should we use,  @Input & @Output decorators  or Services in Angular? What would be the correct use case for each of the features?

I have read about one use case for each.

1. Higher class components --> Use Services
2. Lower class components (Closely related) ---> Use input and output decorators

Can anyone elaborate and explain to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. @Input (Parent to Child Relationship) -> If you want to pass data from Parent to Child component for example
   Component A is Parent and Component B is a child that time we will use @Input
   decorator into child component which is B

   `// app.component.ts (Parent)
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: <div><child [count]="cnt"></child></div> 
   })
   export class AppComponent {
   cnt: number = 10;
   }`

   `// Child...
   import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({...})
   export class ChildComponent {
     @Input()
     cnt: number = 0;
   }`
2. @Output (Child to Parent Relationship) - When you want to pass data from child to parent with EventEmitter

   `@Output() public eventName:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();`
3. No relationship between components - Then used shared service to pass data from component A to Component Z

Comment: Thanks a lot for the assistance. Now it clears on when to use what.